# Why i am not able to pass email id to TO filed while sending email using CI?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi this is my controller function. In my view i set one email variable coming from database into session data. I verified it  in controller whether i am getting it correct it or not. I am getting it perfectly. But when i tried to send that email id as TO field variable it's not working.

```
function do_upload()
{ 
    $config['upload_path'] = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\upload\application';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'doc|docx|pdf';
    $config['max_size'] = '10240';
    $email = $this->session->userdata("employer_email");// If i echo $email; I will get my passed session variable

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {   
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }
    else
    { 
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data()); 

        echo "Resume Successfully uploaded to database.............";
        $file = $data['upload_data']['full_path'];

    $config = Array(
      'protocol' => 'smtp',
      'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
      'smtp_port' => 465,
      'smtp_user' => 'xxx@gmail.com', // change it to yours
      'smtp_pass' => 'xxxx', // change it to yours
      'mailtype' => 'html',
      'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
      'wordwrap' => TRUE
    );


      $this->load->library('email', $config);
      $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
      $this->email->from('xxx@gmail.com'); // change it to yours
      $this->email->to($email); // But here it's not working
      $this->email->subject('Email using Gmail.');
      $this->email->message('Working fine ! !');
      $this->email->attach($file);
      if($this->email->send())
     {
      echo 'Email sent.';
     }
     else
    {
     show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
    }


}
```

Comment: What does `show_error()` tell you?

Comment: you didn't select file to upload............

Comment: According to the code, email will be sent only when upload is successful. By the look of things file uploading is not taking place and hence the email script is not running.

Comment: Your error says 'you didn't select file to upload' and yet you thought the problem was in setting the to field? How? Why?

Comment: yes exactly correct when i debugged it's not going to else part when i kept xxx@gmail.com inplace of $email in TO filed it's working and email working

Comment: xbonez bcz i debugged in two cases in one case it's working and in one case it's not working........working case is xxx@gmail.com in TO filed........non working case is $email in TO filed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $email is passing to the function without the quotes. Think about how it's going to come from the session. If the email in the session is xxx@gmail.com then you're passing the following:

```
$this->email->to(xxx@gmail.com);
```

You want that line to read:

```
$this->email->to('xxx@gmail.com');
```

Try this:

```
$email = '"'.$this->session->userdata("employer_email").'"';
```